# Loop only applies onclick to the last element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to apply an onclick event to some elements with a for of loop.
The thing is that it only applies onclick to the last element of the list 
and I can't find the problem

This is the function that applies the onclick:

```
assign_onclick_output_header = element_id => {
    const id = element_id+"-output"
    const output = document.getElementById(id)
    const output_header = output.getElementsByClassName('card-header')[0]

    output_header.onclick = () => { 
        const state = output_header.classList.contains('opened')
        console.log(state)
        if (state) {
            output_header.classList.remove('opened')
        } else {
            output_header.classList.add('opened')
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the function that calls the function that applies the onclick with a loop:

```
execute = async () => {
    for (const platform_id of this.platforms_ids) {
        const data = {
            platform_id:platform_id,
            command:this.command
        }

        const resp = await this.fetch_output(data)
        this.assign_onclick_output_header(platform_id)
    }
}
```

The platforms_ids value:

```
platforms_ids: (4) [598, 612, 641, 671]
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="output-container" class="card-body">
<div class="card mt-3" id="598-output">
    <div class="card-header" style="cursor:pointer">euroformac (86.109.107.51)</div>
    <div class="card-body">some content</div></div>
<div class="card mt-3" id="612-output">
    <div class="card-header" style="cursor:pointer">fponline (86.109.107.54)</div>
    <div class="card-body">Some content</div>
</div>
<div class="card mt-3" id="641-output">
    <div class="card-header" style="cursor:pointer">formad (86.109.107.239)</div>
    <div class="card-body">Some content</div>
</div>
<div class="card mt-3" id="671-output">
    <div class="card-header" style="cursor:pointer">pen (176.28.115.54)</div>
    <div class="card-body">Some content</div>
</div>
```

I tried to debug but I was unable to find the bug,

thank you guys.

Comment: Could you show us the values in `this.platforms_ids` and the HTML it is searching in?

Comment: @AngelQuesada are you sure that you really closed the <div>'s for id="598-output" and id="output-container"?

Comment: thank you @curveball! I edited the html to post it and forgot that part ;)

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of why you need it this way, it can be done using advanced js features like async generators. You have to set up an async `for of` loop instead of a syncronous one. In the end, `card-header` elements will get onclick handlers, thus, after clicking on them their background will be orange.:

```js
assign_onclick_output_header = element_id => {

    const id = element_id+"-output";
    const output = document.getElementById(id);
    const output_header = output.getElementsByClassName('card-header')[0];

    output_header.onclick = () => { 
        const state = output_header.classList.contains('opened')
        if (state) {
            output_header.classList.remove('opened')
        } else {
            output_header.classList.add('opened')
        }
    }
}

async function* getData(ids) {
   // emulating ajax calls
   for (let platform_id of ids) {
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
        });
        yield platform_id;
   }
}


(async () => {
  let gen = getData([598, 612, 641, 671]);
  for await (let platform_id of gen) {
    assign_onclick_output_header(platform_id);
  }
})();
```

```css
.opened {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="output-container" class="card-body">
<div class="card mt-3" id="598-output">
    <div class="card-header" style="cursor:pointer">euroformac (86.109.107.51)</div>
    <div class="card-body">some content</div><br>
</div>
<div class="card mt-3" id="612-output">
    <div class="card-header" style="cursor:pointer">fponline (86.109.107.54)</div>
    <div class="card-body">Some content</div><br>
</div>
<div class="card mt-3" id="641-output">
    <div class="card-header" style="cursor:pointer">formad (86.109.107.239)</div>
    <div class="card-body">Some content</div><br>
</div>
<div class="card mt-3" id="671-output">
    <div class="card-header" style="cursor:pointer">pen (176.28.115.54)</div>
    <div class="card-body">Some content</div><br>
</div>
</div>
```